# What are distinctive terms?

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, information-retrieval

Here $n$ is the number of distinctive terms in document $d$. What is the meaning of *distinctive*?

[image: TF formula]

My guess is that it's terms that remain after filtering document from terms that aren't necessary, like tweets containing "is" and "are" and "Loooool" are removed it and distinctive terms are the remain words. Am I right or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just the remaining words after stop words (a, is, are, the, etc.) are removed, but combinations of words that frequently appear together (like "global warming" or "cross validation") are considered distinctive terms as well. The list of distinctive terms in a document or set of documents are known as the *vocabulary* for those documents.

Comment: @user That looks more like a tweetspeak to English dictionary. It's a good start, but it doesn't contain multi-word phrases.

Comment: really, Thanks for your time and replying. do you have a background in TF-IDF algorithm?

Comment: @user Nope, just one school project a couple of years ago. :)